# Definition not found for my LWC Component Reference

Tags: lightning-web-components

I added some components to my Dev org and deployed them via a managed package to a Partner Professional org (not sandbox, the partner ones allow Managed-Beta packages).

When i go to a reference page in either org:

https://my-custom-domain.lightning.force.com/docs/component-library/overview/components

I can see a list of my components (woohoo!). Unfortunately, whichever one i click on, it says 'Definition not found'. How does one go about adding documentation to the components to generate there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer to [this migration article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_bundles). Currently `Documentation` is available only for AURA components - by using [DOCUMENTATION COMPONENT](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_documentation.htm) in components bundle. This is not yet available on LWC as `Not currently available` (as stated above reference) .

Comment: Typical of SF it seems...